# Change Current Location from within the app

Tags: iphone, ios, google-maps, cllocation

I am stuck in problem with user current location.

I have an app in which i show events which occur near by of user current location. Everything is fine till now but from now i have to implement the functionality to change city. If i change city then near by events will also change respectively. I want to know that will i be able to change my current location within from app. Or in other words can i change the location in settings of phone within from my app. Any suggestion would be helpful.

Thanks

Comment: Are you talking about Region Format in Settings App on phone?

Comment: Nice question, if you have lat long than you can update your Map respectively.

Comment: @Hirengardhariya-Hi! bro but in next time when location manager will fire for current location it will again set the location which i have rather than which i choose

Comment: i understand, for that you have to save your lat, long of selected location into default preference. when you again check if preference null than current location. if preference not null than current location = preference file value.

Comment: how your problem is solved?

Comment: Are you want the same

Comment: no i want to know that u used googleapis or apple geocode..?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't change Your current location from settings.

If you want to save selected city as your current location then save selected city's longitude and latitude and pass it as your current location to method that gets the near by events so it should work as your current location.

You can save your selected city lat n long in Preference file (or .plist). and when Location updates itself you can check if user have selected city then you pass the lat and long of selected city otherwise your current location lat long. so it will be easier for you.

Hope it Helps!!

Comment: Hello dear but i have use location manager which will use the location which i saved in setting when it will fire it will change the location accordingly

Comment: Ok but you have any example

Comment: it is simple my friend. just save lat n long of selected city when user select any city. and add one condition in locationchangelistener that if there is data saved in file then pass that lat n long. otherwise current location.

Comment: OK i am seeing that Because i haven't made shared preference file till now ;)

Comment: if you don't want that selected city for future use means when you load again if you don't want that data then you can just use class variable of hashmap so that you can store selected city data in it and use wherever you like and will be removed as activity gets finished.

Comment: That is tough to make hash map :) I will use shared preference

Comment: ok.. its up to you. but do mind that you should remove all values from  shared preference when you want to load data from current location otherwise it will get only from saved data in SP.

Answer (score 1):

If you have lat long of the new city then you can set the lat long to location coordinates ....and then you can update events also..

Comment: but in next time when location manager will fire for current location it will again set the location which i have rather than which i choose

Comment: you want to save your last selected location?

Comment: Yeah same the you think

Comment: if you want to save your last location then you can save it using NSUserdefault and next time when location manager launches you can use saved location coordinates easily...

Answer (score 1):

You can not change you current location but you can do this by getting lat long of city.

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=jaipur&sensor=false
```

Using this you can get lat long of other city and pass it as your current location to get the near by events .

Here is nice links related to map [Link](http://rajneesh071.blogspot.com/2013/03/show-route-from-current-location-to.html)